# Do magnets\ magnetic fields become weaker when exposed to para magnetic objects?

Tags: electromagnetism

Do magnets (permanent) become weaker as they are exposed to para-magnetic objects? I was thinking about this after seeing [this](http://www.adamsmagnetic.com/blogs/2012/factors-which-cause-permanent-magnets-to-lose-strength-or-to-demagnetize/).

I am buying a magnet and wish to know if a magnet (permanent) loses its magnetic domain structure or alignment when exposed to para magnetic materials.

Answer (score 3):

A strongly [paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism) material has a magnetic susceptibility of a few hundred parts per million; that is, the field strength inside of a paramagnet is different from the field strength in vacuum starting in the fourth decimal place. This is comparable to the ratio between the earth's natural field (typically about 0.5 gauss) and the surface field of a good permanent magnet (typically about 10<sup>4</sup> gauss).

Storing a permanent magnet near or far from a paramagnetic environment should have about the same effect on its degradation as the difference between storing the permanent magnet aligned north-to-south versus south-to-north.  Not very much.